# Difference between passing a regular and async anonymous function to Task.Run for asynchronous work

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, anonymous-function

What is the difference between

```
ResultType result = await Task.Run(() => GetResultAsync())
```

and

```
ResultType result = await Task.Run(async() => await GetResultAsync())
```

I would speculate that the former would fire and forget `GetResultAsync()`, since it is not awaited, but then how does it get the result? I am surprised that the return type of the former`Task.Run` is `Task<ResultType>` and not `Task<Task<ResultType>>`.

Comment: What is the difference between a to-do list that says "make a sandwich" and a to-do list that says "make a to-do list that says make a sandwich, and then do what's on that list"?  If you can explain to me what the difference is between those two things, I can explain to you what the difference is between those two code snippets.

Comment: I do not understand where your speculation comes from; can you explain better why you are surprised by the thing that surprises you?  The `Task.Run` method is *typed* as taking a `Func<Task<T>>` so why are you surprised that it handles that case correctly?

Comment: Hi Eric, thanks for answering. Let me better explain my speculation/difficulty in understanding...

Comment: ...I was thinking that the return type of GetResultAsync is Task<ResultType>, and [Task.Run would return a Task of the return type, which would be Task<Task<ResultType>>](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/tasks/Task.cs,5650). In the latter example in my question, the return type of await GetResultAsync is ResultType, and Task.Run returns a Task of that return type. I didn't realize [Task.Run behaves differently for functions of tasks versus functions of other types](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/tasks/Task.cs,5740).

Comment: Indeed, the authors of that method anticipated how people would call it and planned accordingly. More generally, there's an interesting type theory fact here: for monadic types there is usually an elegant way to go from `M<M<T>>` to `M<T>`; how that operation is either encoded into the language or made unnecessary by clever API design is an interesting design question. For example: in C# it is *illegal* to make a `Nullable<Nullable<T>>`, so there is never a need to double-unwrap a nullable. As you've seen, the API is designed to avoid `Task<Task<T>>`.

Comment: ... Getting rid of the outer wrapper on an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>` is `SelectMany(x=>x)`.  And so on; different monads use different techniques depending on how they are embedded into the language.

Comment: All that said: the more germane question you should be asking is "why am I doing any of this at all?"  Just write your code as `ResultType result = await GetResultAsync();` and don't mess around with `Task.Run` at all! It's already asynchronous; there's no need to make it *more* asynchronous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both do the same from perspective of result. In both cases the overload `Task.Run<TResult>(Func<Task<TResult>> function)` is used which internally unwraps the task - that's why result is `Task<ResultType>`. The difference between them is equiavalent to the difference between

```
    static Task<T> Compute()
    {
        return GetAsyncResult();
    }
```

and

```
    static async Task<T> Compute()
    {
        return await GetAsyncResult();
    }
```

In the first case the promise is just passed back to the caller, while in the second the state machine is built by compiler around the `Compute` method.

Answer (score 0):

In the first line the 'Task.Run' you start, immediately returns the result of 'GetResultAsync'. That result however, is a Task that can be awaited (by your 'await').
So, you actually 'await' the 'GetResultAsync' method.

In the second line,  you start a Task that does not return immediately, but waits till 'GetResultAsync' (called asynchronously) is finished. The returntype of your Task is 'ResultType'. 
So you 'await' your own Task, that in its turn will only return after awaiting the 'GetResultAsync' method.

In the end, they both accomplish the same result, but in a slightly different manner.